# How to get json path from keys.iter in python

Tags: python, json

I have a very long and complicated JSON file.
In it has a full JSON object PER line.  this is not a `[{},{}]` series.  Just a single JSON then `LF` then another JSON, and on and on for about 258mil lines.

Example:

```
{
    "1": "a", 
    "3": "b", 
    "8": {
        "12": "c", 
        "25": "d"
    }
}  
{
    "1": "a", 
    "3": "b", 
    "8": {
        "12": "c", 
        "24": "d"
    }
}
```

I am trying to get:

```
1
3
8
8|12
8|25 <-- from first line
8|24 <-- from second line
```

I found this code:

```
keylist = []
filepath = '<<myfile.json>>'
with open(filepath) as fp:
   for cnt, line in enumerate(fp):
       print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, line))
       for key, value in data.iteritems():
          keylist.append(key)
```

This gives me a roster of all elements, but I also need the `path`

Comment: What would be the relative path? Do you have an example? Where `data` comes from in your code snippet?

Comment: in the `I am trying to get` section, those numbers are actually the keys. `8|24` is the path to the key `24`.  `24` is a child of `8`.  By saying `8|24` I'm getting the path.

Comment: keep a storage of all keys so far, This is the path to the current key. Simply keep a storage of previous keys so far. But you would need to do away with `iteritems` and traverse it manualy

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import ndjson

# Recursively print the path to dictionary keys
def get_dict_path(m_dict, parent_path = None):
    for k,v in m_dict.items():
        if parent_path is None:
            print(k)
        else:
            print(parent_path + "|" + k)

        if isinstance(v, dict):
            if parent_path is None:
                get_dict_path(v, k)
            else:
                get_dict_path(v, parent_path + "|" + k)

# Deep merge two dictionaries            
def merge(source, destination):
    for key, value in source.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            node = destination.setdefault(key, {})
            merge(value, node)
        else:
            destination[key] = value
    return destination


if __name__ == "__main__":

    filepath = <<your_file>>
    with open(filepath,'r') as fp:
        str_data = fp.read().replace(" ","").replace("\n","").replace("}{","}\n{")
    json_data = ndjson.loads(str_data)

    final_dict = {}
    for json_elem in json_data:
        final_dict = merge(final_dict, json_elem)

    get_dict_path(final_dict)
```

Comment: thank you Simon.  question.  do I call `get_dict_path()` and `m_dict` will be the line (one full json object)? or do I do something first?

Comment: Sorry @arcee123, I oversaw, that you have multiple JSON-like elements in your file, though it is not a **valid** JSON file. You first should parse this into some structure which could be processed properly, e.g. a list of JSONs.

Comment: you have to recurse using not only current key but also parent_key so far. For example: `if isinstance(v, dict):  get_dict_path(v, parent_path + "|" + k)` Else what you have works only for two-levels deep; then the path is incorrect

Comment: Hmm, you should check if parent_path is `not None` also, else simply rucurse on current key. :)

Comment: Also correct. Missed those scenarios due to lack of available exmaples ;)